# Extending React components in TypeScript

Tags: oop, generics, inheritance, reactjs, typescript

I'm using React.js with TypeScript. Is there any way to create React components that inherit from other components but have some additional props/states?

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
interface BaseStates {
    a: number;
}

class GenericBase<S extends BaseStates> extends React.Component<void, S> {
    protected getBaseInitialState(): BaseStates {
        return { a: 3 };
    }
}

class Base extends GenericBase<BaseStates> {
    getInitialState(): BaseStates {
        return super.getBaseInitialState();
    }
}

interface DerivedStates extends BaseStates {
    b: number;
}

class Derived extends GenericBase<DerivedStates> {
    getInitialState(): DerivedStates {
        var initialStates = super.getBaseInitialState() as DerivedStates; // unsafe??
        initialStates.b = 4;
        return initialStates
    }
}
```

However, this will fail if I call `this.setState` in `Derived`, I get a TypeScript error (parameter of type `DerivedStates` is not assignable to type `S`). I suppose this is not a TypeScript-specific thing, but a general limitation of mixing inheritance with generics (?). Is there any type-safe workaround for this?

**UPDATE**

The solution I settled on (based on the answer of David Sherret):

```
interface BaseStates {
    a: number;
}

class GenericBase<S extends BaseStates> extends React.Component<void, S> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = this.getInitialState();
    }

    getInitialState(): S {
        return { a: 3 } as S;
    }

    update() {
        this.setState({ a: 7 } as S);
    }
}

interface DerivedStates extends BaseStates {
    b: number;
}

class Derived extends GenericBase<DerivedStates> {
    getInitialState(): DerivedStates {
        var initialStates = super.getInitialState();
        initialStates.b = 4;
        return initialStates;
    }

    update() {
        this.setState({ a: 7, b: 4 });
    }
}
```

Comment: I also struggled to find the answer. Basically what I want is pass `A<DerivedProps>` component to `A<BaseProps>` interface to get some basic props type checking both inside and outside of `A`.

Comment: But later I've found that the situation is similar to assigning `DerivedProps => void` to `BaseProps => void`. The first function(or class constructor) cannot inherit the second one.

Comment: Consider using `abstract` classes/functions. ([see answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866534/extending-react-components-in-typescript#63767838))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set only a few properties of the state at once in `Derived` by using a type assertion:

```
this.setState({ b: 4 } as DerivedStates); // do this
this.setState({ a: 7 } as DerivedStates); // or this
this.setState({ a: 7, b: 4 });            // or this
```

By the way, no need to have different names for `getInitialState`... you could just do:

```
class GenericBase<S extends BaseStates> extends React.Component<void, S> {
    constructor() {
        super();        
        this.state = this.getInitialState();
    }

    protected getInitialState() {
        return { a: 3 } as BaseStates as S;
    }
}

class Derived extends GenericBase<DerivedStates> {
    getInitialState() {
        var initialStates = super.getInitialState();
        initialStates.b = 4;
        return initialStates;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. For your solution, I get an error for the second line of the constructor:

    `type 'BaseStates' is not assignable to type 'S'`

which is not surprising, as `S` is a subclasss of `BaseStates`.

Comment: @Thegaram i was just fixing that. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! Still not sure about how safe these downcasts are, but my question is answered.

Comment: do you know why it won't work with optional states? If I set `a` to optional, at `GenericBase.getInitialState` I get an error: `neither type '{ a: number; }' nor type 'S' is assignable to the other `

Comment: @Thegaram I had to be more explicit to get it to work: `return { a: 3 } as BaseStates as S`. Kind of annoying, but maybe there's a reason. I updated the answer.

Comment: As a heads up, this clobbers type checking on your state as `S` could be *any* interface that extends `BaseStates`. If you do `return { a: 3, derp: true } as BaseStates as S` it won't throw an error, which *technically* makes sense, because there's no way to know if `S` has a `derp` property on it. Just something to be aware of because that might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: Consider using `abstract` classes/functions. ([see answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866534/extending-react-components-in-typescript#63767838))

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Component } from 'react'


abstract class TestComponent<P = {}, S = {}, SS = any> extends Component<P, S, SS> {
  abstract test(): string
}


type Props = {
  first: string,
  last: string,
}

type State = {
  fullName: string,
}

class MyTest extends TestComponent<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      fullName: `${props.first} ${props.last}`
    }
  }

  test() {
    const { fullName } = this.state
    return fullName
  }
}
```