# Extend a React Component Class with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oop, generics, inheritance

I am trying to do this with a more complex base class than [Extending React components in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866534/extending-react-components-in-typescript)

Here is my base class:

```
export class RootContainer<
  P extends RootContainerProps & RootStateFromProps & RootDispatchFromProps,
  S extends RootContainerState
> extends React.Component<P, S> {
  constructor(props: P) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.getInitialState();
  }

  getInitialState(): S {
    return { modalIsOpen: false } as S;
  }
```

And then I try to extend as follows:

```
interface MyReservationsContainerProps extends RootContainerProps {
  // Normal component props
}

interface MyReservationsContainerState extends RootContainerState {
  allReservations: Reservation[];
  selectableReservations: Reservation[];
  mode: number;
}

class MyReservationsContainer extends RootContainer<
  MyReservationsContainerProps,
  MyReservationsContainerState
> {
```

But I get this error:

> No base constructor has the specified number of type
>   arguments.ts(2508)

Any typescript guru's able to help me?

Comment: So I figured this out - the issue was that the base class was wrapped in a redux connect() HOF and then exported, and I actually needed to export the standard non-connect() version, and then wrap the derived class in connect() after. What is the best course of action here - just to delete the question?

Comment: No leave it on ... Helped me