# TS2508 (TS) No base constructor has the specified number of type arguments when trying to extend a React Component class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am quite new to React. I inherited code which inherits a `MyTable` component from [Antd Table](https://ant.design/components/table/). I do not want to change that architecture.

For other reasons, I did a complete package update, I am now at Antd 3.24.0, React(-dom) 16.10.2, Typescript 3.6.4. Previously (Antd 2.10.0, React 15.5.3, Typescript 2.2.1) the 2nd line (within a  `tsx` file) worked just fine

```
import { Table } from "antd";
class MyTable extends Table<Interfaces.SummaryViewEntry> { }
```

Now, after updating to the newest package version, webpack refuses to transpile with the following error:

> TS2508 (TS) No base constructor has the specified number of type arguments.

Just in case you are interested: In `interfaces.ts`, we defined something similar to the following:

```
export interface SummaryViewEntry {
    LedgerName: string,
    Value: number,
}
```

The corresponding declaration file `node_modules\antd\lib\table\Table.d.ts` reads

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { TableProps } from './interface';
declare const _default: React.ComponentClass<Pick<TableProps<any>, "loading" | "footer" | "style" | "title" | "scroll" | "size" | "children" | "className" | "prefixCls" | "locale" | "getPopupContainer" | "onChange" | "dataSource" | "expandIcon" | "tableLayout" | "columns" | "bordered" | "bodyStyle" | "pagination" | "rowKey" | "dropdownPrefixCls" | "rowSelection" | "components" | "rowClassName" | "expandedRowRender" | "defaultExpandAllRows" | "defaultExpandedRowKeys" | "expandedRowKeys" | "expandIconAsCell" | "expandIconColumnIndex" | "expandRowByClick" | "onExpandedRowsChange" | "onExpand" | "indentSize" | "onRowClick" | "onRow" | "onHeaderRow" | "useFixedHeader" | "showHeader" | "childrenColumnName" | "sortDirections">, any>;
export default _default;
```

Any advice is appreciated.

### EDIT: Background information

[image: Screenshot of Warning in Visual Studio]

#### Webpack.config after update

```
var path = require('path');
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');

module.exports = {
    entry: `${APP_DIR}/index.tsx`,
    target: 'node',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/, use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [['@babel/env', {
                                "targets": { "browsers": ["ie >= 11"] }
                            }]]
                        }
                    },
                    "ts-loader"]
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'css-loader' },
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader' },
            { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'css-loader!less-loader' }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

#### Webpack.config before update

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "bundle": ["babel-polyfill", "whatwg-fetch", "./src/index.tsx"]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [[
                        'env',
                        {
                            "targets": {
                                "browsers": ["ie >= 11"]
                            }
                        }
                    ]]
                }
            },"ts-loader"] },
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },
            { test: /\.less$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader!less-loader") }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css")
    ]
};
```

### References

- [Extend a React Component Class with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730879/extend-a-react-component-class-with-typescript) - not helpful for my issue, I think?
- https://www.v2ex.com/t/530586 - I cannot read that
- https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/17245 - looks close, but I am now sure what I should actually do.

Comment: Could you post your webpack.config -- specifically the rule for your babel loader? Also, what is the file extension of MyTable?

Comment: @JayKariesch I expanded my question accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried passing the type values to the extended component's constructor with super()?

class MyTable extends Table<Interfaces.SummaryViewEntry> { 
     constructor(props) {
        // props = { LenderName: '', Value: 0 } 
       super(props)
    }
}

Comment: @JayKariesch I am not sure what you mean - so no.